# Saving results from for loop as a vector in r

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have the following for loop which prints numbers from 1 to 10:

```
for (i in 1:10) {print (i) }
```

How do I save the results as a vector, instead of just printing them to the console?

If I try:

```
my_vector <- for (i in 1:10) {print (i) }
```

Then call `my_vector`, I get:

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling `print` will always print the result of each iteration to the console. If you leave in the `print` command, then you might get unwanted output.

Your main problem is that you did not initialize `my_vector` before the `for` loop.  You could instead do the following and not get the `print` side-effect.

```
my_vector <- vector("numeric", 10L)
for(i in 1:10) my_vector[i] <- i
my_vector
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But note that this is just the same as doing the following with `sapply`, but in this case you need no declaration and you can assign the result to a vector.

```
my_vector2 <- sapply(1:10, function(x) x)
my_vector2
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: equivalently: `sapply(1:10, identity)`, `sapply(1:10, force)` or `sapply(1:10, "(")`.  Or, with vapply: `vapply(1:10, "(", 1L)`

Comment: Ah, `force` is what I was thinking of earlier.  That `"("` method is definitely new to me though.  Never thought to do that.

Comment: @RichScriven is there a way to do this with `dplyr` or anything from the `tidyverse`? Just asking as a theoretical question

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively

```
my_vector = c()
for(i in 1:5){my_vector=c(my_vector,i)}
my_vector
```

Answer (score 0):

Following form can also be used:

```
> my_vector = c()
> for(i in 1:5)       my_vector[length(my_vector)+1] = i
> my_vector
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: This is growing an object in memory which is Circle II of [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)