# for loop with decimals and store results in a vector

Tags: r, loops, vector

I'm working on a for loop in R, and I had to store the results in a vector. I know that this is a quite common answer, and my problem is not there, but let's proceed with order.

I got those data:

```
# here the data
alpha <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
beta <- c(0.1,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6)
data <- data.frame(alpha, beta)
```

And I make a simple function that select the data above a certain threshold:

```
# here the function
funny <- function(x,k)
{x[x[,2]>=k,]}

# here an example of the function
funny(data,0.5)

      alpha beta
2     2  0.5
5     5  0.5
6     6  0.6
```

But what I want is the number of the rows that go over the threshold, so:

```
# here the result wanted
nrow(funny(data,0.5))
[1] 3
```

So I got a question: how many rows go over the threshold at the variation of k, the parameter of the function? And I would like to have the result in a vector. I created a for loop, looking at

[For loop in R with increments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287364/for-loop-in-r-with-increments)

[Saving results from for loop as a vector in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330849/saving-results-from-for-loop-as-a-vector-in-r)

And I created this: first of all let's see if everything is all right:

```
# here the sequence   
s <-seq(0.1,0.6, by = 0.1)

# here the I loop
for(i in s) {print(nrow(funny(data,i)))}
[1] 6
[1] 5
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 1
```

But clearly this is not stored in a vector. The problem is here. I tried:

```
# already written sequence   
s <-seq(0.1,0.6, by = 0.1)

# here the empty vector
vec <- vector("numeric")

# here the II problematic loop
for(i in s) {vec[i]<-(nrow(funny(data,i)))}
vec
```

And here the result I do not want, I expected something like `[1] 6 5 4 4 3 1`

`[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Furthermore infos:
I tried something like this:

```
# sequence * 10
s <-seq(1,6, by = 1)

# here the vector
vec <- vector("numeric")
# and the III loop, that it works now.

for(i in s) {vec[i]<-(nrow(funny(data,i/10)))}
vec
[1] 6 5 5 4 3 1
```

But I do not like this, because I do not understand why the III works and why the II loop no.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try with `sapply` which will return a vector

```
sapply(s, function(x) nrow(funny(data, x)))

#[1] 6 5 4 4 3 1
```

As far as why your loop II is not working. If you do,

```
for(i in s) {
  print(i)
}
```

You'll get

```
[1] 0.1
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.3
[1] 0.4
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.6
```

So when you are trying to store in your loop II `vec[i] <-`, you are actually doing `vec[0.1]` in first case which is not correct.

To correct your loop, try

```
for(i in seq_along(s))  {vec[i]<-(nrow(funny(data,s[i])))}
vec
#[1] 6 5 4 4 3 1
```

Where `seq_along(s)` would return `#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6`.