# save an output into a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have the following function which finds the distinct number of cases belonging to 4 different factors. `test` is a list containing 4 `dataframes`

```
for (i in test){
  i<-i%>%distinct(FileNumber)%>%nrow()
  print(i)
}
```

when i run this, I get the following output

```
[1] 38
[1] 129
[1] 1868
[1] 277
```

However I want this output to be saved into another vector called my_vector. So that `my_vector` is

```
38 129 1868 277
```

So I tried the following based on this answer I found 
[Saving results from for loop as a vector in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330849/saving-results-from-for-loop-as-a-vector-in-r)

```
library(dplyr)

my_vector<-vector("numeric",4L)

for (i in test){
  my_vector[i]<-i%>%distinct(FileNumber)%>%nrow()
}
```

However when I run this I get the following message

```
Error in my_vector[i] <- i %>% distinct(FileNumber) %>% nrow() : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'
```

How do I get the earlier output I listed saved into a vector?

Comment: `sapply(test, function(a) length(unique(a$FileNumber)))` might work. If you must stick with a `for` loop, your pre-allocation of the vector should be fine, but you'll want to iterate *by index* instead: `for (ind in seq_len(test)) { my_vector[i] <- test[[i]] %>% ...; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to index `my_vector` with a `list`-like object.

For instance:

```r
mylist <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
myvec <- numeric(length(mylist))
for (i in mylist) {
  myvec[i] <- nrow(distinct(i, cyl))
}
```

On the first (and second in this example) iteration, `i` is a frame, so `myvec[i]` is equivalent to `myvec[mtcars]`, which does not make sense.

Instead, loop over the *index* of the list of frames, ala:

```r
library(dplyr)
mylist <- list(mtcars, mtcars)
myvec <- numeric(length(mylist))
for (i in seq_len(length(mylist))) {
  myvec[i] <- test[[i]] %>% distinct(cyl) %>% nrow()
}
myvec
# [1] 3 3
```

or just do something like:

```r
sapply(mylist, function(l) l %>% distinct(cyl) %>% nrow())
# [1] 3 3
```

BTW: this is just as easy in base-R with:

```r
sapply(mylist, function(l) length(unique(l[["cyl"]])))
# [1] 3 3
```

Comment: For the curious, the difference between `1:length(test)` and `seq_len(length(test))` is effectively "nothing" until `test` is accidentally of length 0 (from the perspective of code resilience to all lengths, including zero). See the difference between `1:0` and `seq_len(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with a list of data frames or matrices

```
d <- list(a = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 20),
            b = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10),
            c = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 50))

my_vect <- c()
for (i in seq_along(d)){
  n <- nrow(d[[i]]) 
  my_vect[i] <- n
}

my_vect 
[1] 20 10 50
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `unlist()` and if that doesn't work, then add `as.vector()` in your pipe:

```
for (i in test){
  i<-i %>% distinct(FileNumber) %>% nrow() %>% unlist()
  print(i)
}
```

If that does not come out as a vector then:

```
for (i in test){
  i<-i %>% distinct(FileNumber) %>% nrow() %>% unlist() %>% as.vector()
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: The logic of `... %>% nrow()` is not contested, so there should be no need for `unlist`. The issue is that the OP was trying to index a vector with a frame, something like `my_vector[ mtcars ]`, which is not meaningful.